# доступ из одного <td> к другому в одной строке таблицы

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Добрый день, у меня есть таблица которая выводится для списка объектов (каждый объект - 1 строка).

```
    <table id="criterionTable" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
                <thead class="table-head">
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>add</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="criteriaTableId">
                </tbody>
            </table>

 function appendTableRows(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $('#criterionTable > tbody:last-child').append("<tr>" +
            "<td>"+value.title+"</td>" +
            "<td><button class='addButton btn-primary btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button></td>" +
            "</tr>");
    });
}
```

Хочу чтоб при нажатии на любую из кнопок во второй колонке, я получал значение соответствующее ей из первой (name).

написал такой скрипт, но он не работает:

```
  $('.addButton').click(function () {
    console.log($(this < 'tr:first').text());
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.addButton', function () {
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuywmev3/3/)

Comment: Станислав Грот, не работает..

Comment: .text() подсвечивает как Unresolved function or method text, и в консоль ничего не выводит

Comment: @Aleksei код работает, проверить можно на jsfiddle, 'Unresolved function or method text' Вам скорее всего пишет phpStorm.

Comment: я пофиксил проблему с unresolved function, но по прежнему в консоль ничего не выводится. У меня эта таблица заполняется отдельно от вьюшки в jquery, Может в этом проблема?  Добавил в первый пост

Comment: @Aleksei изменил ответ, теперь рассчитан на динамическое добавление

Comment: спасибо вам большое, так работает. ПС. не могли бы вы объяснить в чём принципиальная разница между этими двумя способами?

Comment: @Aleksei первый способ добавляет обработчик к тем, которые уже есть на странице, on() используется для динамически добавляемых елементов

Comment: спасибо ещё раз!